# Writing OpenGL 4 software, even though video card supports only 3.2?

Tags: graphics-card, opengl, ati-mobility-radeon

I am attempting a purchase of a laptop, that has ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5650 video card.

According to [this website](http://www.amd.com/us/products/notebook/graphics/ati-mobility-hd-5700/pages/hd-5650-specs.aspx), that video cart supports only OpenGL version 3.2 .
But I would like to start learning OpenGL 4 to develop graphical software.

My question is:

Is there anyway I could still write and test software that utilizes OpenGL 4, despite using a video card that doesn't support it, through some kind of emulation?

Comment: OpenGL level is determined by the driver, not the hardware.  You can create an OpenGL 4 context for a card that isn't OpenGL 4-class, but be prepared for a lot of the feature detection APIs to return false or be implemented in software.

Comment: @BenVoigt - This isn't entirely true.  The hardware itself supports certain versions of DirectX and OpenGL.  A DirectX 9 only card can never support Direct X 11.2.

Comment: @JamesC - Why don't you learn how to program in OpenGL 3.2, then once you understand the framework, purchase hardware that supports the current version of OpenGL 4.x  Otherwise the hardware in question does not support 4.2

Comment: @Ramhound: A DirectX9-class card won't perform operations introduced in DirectX11.  That's why APIs such as DirectX and OpenGL have feature detection functions.  You can use the newer API as long as you have a new enough driver (or in the case of DirectX, new enough Windows), but some of its features won't be available, or will be extremely slow due to being processed without direct hardware support.

Comment: @Ramhound - I have acquired a modern literature that utilizes OpenGL 4. Plainly speaking, I don't know anything about OpenGL, so I just wanted to find the most modern literature for the latest version. Latest versions of libraries tend to give many new features that simplify and speed up many operations, and make older ones deprecated.

Comment: @BenVoigt - The card in question doesn't have ANY drivers that support OpenGL 4.x which means it won't be possible even if the hardware could handle it.  Additionally everything I have read about DirectX and OpenGL support indicates that both the hardware and driver has to support the version your trying to target.

Comment: @James: Graphics APIs don't really work that way.  New versions definitely don't "simplify".

Comment: @JamesC - OpenGL is OpenGL.  The only difference might be in the case of say a 32-bit vs 64-bit vector command which only exits in a later revision.

Comment: In OpenGL most of the difference between versions is whether you have to use extension loading to gain access to certain functions.

Comment: I was interested in difference between OpenGL 4 and 3, but it is not a SE style of question, and so was afraid to ask it. Does it mean I can learn OGL 3 and I won't be "century behind" modern development ? And can I still use modern OpenGL 4 literature and tutorials, or will I need to search for older ones ?